# Magnetic Flux through a superconducting coil

Tags: electromagnetic-induction

So I came across questions involving coils with wires in superconducting state, where the only method to solve them was to take magnetic flux through the coil to be constant. I failed to understand why.

Why should magnetic flux through a superconductor loop be constant?